# Cout c++ in many lines

Tags: c++, cout

I want to print a large message in c++ using cout.

example:

```
cout<<"Camera could not be opened in the requested access mode, because another
              application (possibly on another host) is using the camera."<<endl;
```

but I get an error.

any help?

Comment: .. and what is the error?

Comment: If it's an error message, it should arguably be sent to `cerr` rather than `cout`.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this:

```
 cout<<"Camera could not be opened in the requested access mode, because another "
          "application (possibly on another host) is using the camera."<<endl;
```

or

```
 cout<<"Camera could not be opened in the requested access mode, because another\n"
          "application (possibly on another host) is using the camera."<<endl;
```

In C and C++, two strings next to each other will be concatenated by the compiler.

Comment: Original version should also work (maybe with some excess whitespace)

Comment: That'd be a pretty long error message. Might want a newline in there somewhere.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Really? Both g++ and clang++ objects when I have a newline in the middle of a string. Not sure which compiler you are using...

Comment: You need a \ at the end to make it work, just like a multiline macro if you don't use extra quotes.  The extra quotes are generally more readable and preferable imo.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: That would also work, but that's just hard to read and error prone. I often use " ... " "...." over multiple lines for long text messages, and it typically formats nicely on the screen that way too. Don't think I've ever used backslash in such a case. What's the benefit (aside from saving one character, but diskspace is relatively cheap these days).

Comment: @MatsPetersson I totally agree.  You can make it work without quotes, but it just looks wrong to me.  It also tends to break syntax highlighters.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of a version with the backslash.   C++11 allows "raw" string literals without it but this isn't one of those either.

Answer (score 2):

You can't split normal string literals across multiple lines directly. I think you can split them across lines using the concatenation character. However, that also wouldn't embed newlines. To get these you'd need to use `\n`. I think you can use raw stringliterals though:

```
char const* strcont = "foo\
bar";
char const* strcat = "foo"
                     "bar";
char const* strraw = R"(foo
bar)";
```

The first two strings are the same: adjacent strings are concatenated. The third one also contains a newline.